# Pixelated Lines Appearing

Tags: 14.04

These random lines started appearing on screen. They go away after restarting computer. How can I get rid of them? What problem is this? Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: They didn't just started appearing. It happens after waking up from suspension, you have a Nvidia graphics card with Nvidia drivers and a reboot fixes it.

Comment: So do I need to reinstall my drivers to fix this issue?

Comment: No but I don't know how to fix either. The comment is a hint for you to edit your question and post the relevant details, pretty much what's in my succinct comment above (unless I'm mistaken, apparently not), along with hardware specs (graphics), driver version and how it was installed.